# Android post method , get result

Tags: android

I upload file to my server with post method. This part is OK. But it cannot read result properly.

It must returns : {"id":"5" , "url":"http://aaaaaaaa/bnm.jpg"}.

But it returns : 64bnm.jpg[] .

Relative code snippet :

```
public void uploadFile() throws IOException {
            Log.i("tago", "PageFragment1 resim gonderme islemi");
            HashMap<String, String> postDataParams = new HashMap<>();
            postDataParams.put("placeID", nameofChannel);
            postDataParams.put("img", image);
            postDataParams.put("id", SharedPrefIdAl());
            URL url;
            String response = "";
            try {
                url = new URL("http://185.22.187.60/shappy/place_photos/place_picture.php");

                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);


                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
                try {
                    BufferedReader in;
                    if (conn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                        String inputline = in.readLine();
                        Log.i("tago", "kanal for " + inputline);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(inputline);
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                        yenikanalid = jsonObject.optString("id");
                        yenikanalurl = jsonObject.optString("photo");
                        Log.i("tago", "kanal for kanalid " + yenikanalid + "kanalurl " + yenikanalurl);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
```

I read inputline from logcat. Why is this happening ?

Comment: if you catch an exception it is usually helpful for debugging to print it to logcat. Your last catch does nothing.

Comment: Also, you are doing a GET, not a POST. With GET you can't upload files.

Comment: I also use "POST" i just try it last time , about exception i follow you.